# jQuery animated zoom on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, css

I've got a great effect where you hover your mouse over a particular element and it scales bigger.  I did this simply with:

```
$('#element_to_scale').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({zoom: 2});
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({zoom: 1});
});
```

Problem is this doesn't work on firefox :(.  I read now that firefox is the only browser which doesn't support css zoom?  Seems very strange... so what's the best approach to animating a zooming mechanism with jQuery above?

Comment: CSS3 Transforms should help you.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, can I easily animate css3 transforms with jQuery?

Comment: AFAIK not, but there is a lightweight plugin for that: https://github.com/lrbabe/jquery.transform.js

Comment: Created an answer out of these infos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can user css transform with scale, all in your css.

```
#element_to_scale {
    -moz-transition: transform 0.5s linear 0s;
}
#element_to_scale:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Well this definitely works, but not animated.  It just pops up immediately.  I guess I have to implement my own animation mechanism with setInterval?

Comment: just reading some firefox documentation, looks like the transform 0.5s should animate this, but only works on firefox 4.0 while I have 3.6.

Comment: FF4 will be released next week ;). I think you should detect the "transform" and "transition" rules support with something like Modernizr and use jQuery when not fully supported.

Comment: Is zoom part of the css standard?  Does ff4 now support zoom?  If not, what's the standard way I should handling zooming across browsers?

Comment: This is not al ALL even close to what the OP asks for. It's not even cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS3 transforms](http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-transform/), like

```
-moz-transform: scale(2); 
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
```

, but currently you cannot animate them with basic jQuery.

However, you can use a jQuery plugin for that, like [jquery.transform.js](https://github.com/lrbabe/jquery.transform.js).

Please note the IE9 also supports the `transform` property, I found some info about it in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9).