# Landscape printing css IE11 mvc5 razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css, internet-explorer, razor

So I have been searching for how to print a pretty basic razor html page and really haven't found an answer. The page in question just has a regular html table and some viewbag data. Printing in landscape mode used to be really simple so I'm having a hard time believing this is a functionality that just disappeared. 
I am using IE 11 and CSS3, an MVC5 project with razor. It does not need to be functional in any other browser either.
here's all the things I have tried

example 1: does not change print landscape, the double @'s are to escape the razor @ usage

```
 @@media print
{@@page {size: landscape}}
```

example 2: also does not change print landscape

```
@media print{@page {size: landscape}}
```

example 3:
for this one I tried a bunch of different variations with the margins and the width and height settings. I also tried changing body to @page, @@page, and to a div IDs or class names. It sort of works, but it never takes up the full page length and is always shifted in some direction or another.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
         body{
             margin: 150px 10px 20px 50px;
                -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
                -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
                transform: rotate(90deg);
             width: 10px;
            }
    </style>
```

I feel like there has to be a way to do this, it used to be pretty simple by using this example.

example 4: however this one also does not change print orientation and instead gives the error of "CSS3.0: size is not a known CSS property name."

```
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
                 @page {
size: landscape;
}
            </style>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I know there are several threads on this topic, however none of the answers did it for me.
Here are the threads I checked out, I checked out more, but these seemed to have the most varied answers so I included them.

1. [Landscape printing with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201580/landscape-printing-with-css?rq=1)
2. [How to print HTML in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969122/how-to-print-html-in-landscape)
3. [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)