# css3 rotate not working in ie9

Tags: css

I found this useful link which explains rotation in IE9
[CSS3 transform: rotate; in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9)

unfortunately using either of these does not work

```
.mark.festival:hover{
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

I have seen in various places that both these rules work for IE9 though mostly I am reading that you need the -ms prefix

http://www.wanderfest.com is the link if you want to check it

the site is not in quirks mode as suggested here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/2567faea-fcea-4ddf-9116-1e2c703ee2e7/

Comment: Are you trolling us? Rotating 360degrees does effectively nothing.

Comment: He might be using a transition.

Comment: Transitions are not supported in IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That support on caniuse.com has a caveat: you need to use the MS's `filter`: This translator will convert CSS3 transforms to MS matrices for filters: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Example:

```
 #transformedObject {
      -moz-transform:    rotate(360deg);
      -o-transform:      rotate(360deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform:         rotate(360deg);

      /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

      /* IE6 and 7 */ 
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
           M11=1,
           M12=0,
           M21=0,
           M22=1,
           SizingMethod='auto expand');
 }
```