# css3 rotation doesn't work in IE9

Tags: css, rotation, internet-explorer-9

This code allows me to slowly rotate images whenever the mouse is over one of them.

```
 .foo img {
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
     .foo img:hover {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
          transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
```

It works in FF18 and Opera. However, I can't get it to work on IE9, even is -ms-transform should be the proper solution.
IE9 acts as if there's no specific css `img:hover` rule.
Any hints?
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9

Comment: IE9 doesn't support transitions. But it is perfectly capable of hover and rotate.

Comment: Welcome to the world of web design my friend

Comment: Gosh, as usual IE9 doesn't support something... I should have wondered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://modernizr.com/download/

Modernizr should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use js for this particular task, but I've added modernizr to my bookmarks.