# Rotate a HTML Page In IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, transform

I have an HTML document that consists of two pages. The first is A4 portrait size and the second is A4 landscape size. I have this setup for IE9 so that on screen it displays in a readable format but if you print it, it rotates the second page by -90 degrees (so that it prints on A4 properly) using

```
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

This also uses a translate to reposition the page properly. This is applied to a div which each page is embedded in. Within that is just tables.

This works fine in IE9 but in IE6 (and I assume IE7 and IE8) this doesn't work as earlier versions do not support transforms. Is there any way of doing this in IE6?

Comment: IE6 is dead: http://ie6funeral.com/

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://caniuse.com/#search=Rotate

Comment: For earlier IE's you probably had to do PDF out of html and rotate it

Comment: PDF is always going to be a better option, because it's the one and only way that you're going to be able to guarantee 100% that what goes to the printer is what you EXPECT to go to the printer.  For instance, some browsers drop backgrounds, or render fonts differently.  PDF removes those limitations.

Comment: Also, i found something about `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix`, dont have time to check it through, se here http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Comment: Take a look at this question, I think the details about -sand-transform: rotate(10deg); mat be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9

Comment: @Oriol Yes, tell that to the thousands (millions?) of users IE6 still has (in particular some corporate environments where you **must** use IE6)

Comment: @NullUserException If we stop developing for IE6, those corporate environments will be forced to update the browser. "*The only way to truly force the web to embrace modern open standards is to invalidate old technology.*" (http://occupyflash.org/)

Comment: I have to support IE6. PDF is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

rotation=1 means it will rotate 90 degrees. The base is 90, therefore 2 = 180, 3= 270 and so on.

Comment: This kind of works in that it rotates the page but it is squashed up in the top half of the page and doesn't fit the page like I would expect. Plus the quality of text has been compromised.