# How to rotate a column text in a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I'm getting tired to trying to rotate the column text from a table in html.

This is what I have, it just works in chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9.
http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/scores/listscores

I was seeing these examples about the vertical text. I'm using IE9 and it looks good, I supposed they are using something like a canvas, I really not sure.

http://jsfiddle.net/R4JvP/11/
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm

The second link is what I'm interested show all the header columns in `rotation: (-90)deg` How can I implement this in all browsers?

Comment: Check this link out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9

Should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);`

Answer (score 0):

```
-moz-transform: rotate Firefox 4+
-webkit-transform: rotate Safari 5+, Chrome 10+
-ms-transform: rotate Internet Exlorer 9+
transform: rotate
```