# Rotate a text 90 degree in IE8 doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I had a text rotated in all browsers except in IE8. I tried to use this method (matrix):

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-2.755455294239536e-16, M12=-1.5, M21=1.5, M22=-2.755455294239536e-16, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

but it didn't work !!
 can someone help? is there anything new about this issue?

Comment: Doesn't just `filter` (not `-ms-filter`) work?

Comment: didn't work does not describe the issue.

Comment: have you used it for rotation `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);`

Comment: I have nothing duplicated.. and no position at all in my span and even heigher and lower in my HTMl arround the span

Comment: I tried         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
and also didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use filter property for supporting IE8. Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/bavehako/1/)***.

you can change the degree by by defining the integer value (0,1,2,3)

```
div
{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  -ms-transform:rotate(9deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1); /*FOR IE8*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: take the Demo link and try it in IE8 ... it wont work !

Comment: I've tested in IE tester tool and it work. let me upload a screenshot here. after that I'll check with `browserstack` .

Comment: this one works well but 3 instead of 1   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

Comment: The issue was that I had a non correct width on my span

Comment: okay! so your problem solved now? if yes then you may vote it

Answer (score 0):

IE8 won't support most of the mordern features. Try if mordernizr js helps..

http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may try some thing like

```
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

90deg value need to be adjusted as per your requirement

original article as follows http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

there is also a hack for older IE version as follows

```
-sand-transform: rotate(10deg);
```

more info here [CSS3 transform: rotate; in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865167/css3-transform-rotate-in-ie9)

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried it and doesnt work and by doesnt work I mean It does not rotate

Comment: `-ms-transform` doesn't work for IE8. you've to use filter for IE8.

Comment: I tried -sand-transform: rotate(10deg); and didnt work in IE8